# Why do I have incompatible types error when Iterate Map in Java using keySet()?

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration, incompatibletypeerror

sI have Class 1 where I have

`protected Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();` 
I have Class 2 that extends Class1 and where I do

`List list = this.dao.createSQLQuery(query, this.parameter);`

createSQLQuery method for dao looks like this:

```
public List createSQLQuery(final String query, final Map parameter) {

                    for (final String key : parameter.keySet()) {

                     . . .
} }
```

Why do I have a error in the for cycle line - “incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String”?

As I understand my case is not the raw type issue because I declare `parameter` as Map<String, Object> so `parameter.keySet()` has to return set of Strings

Comment: Change `Map parameter` to `Map<String, Object> parameter`.

Comment: Thanks. It helps with the initial error but generate the next one

"name clash: createSQLQuery(String,Map<String,Object>) in DaoImpl and createSQLQuery(String,Map) in Dao have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other"

Comment: Do the same for `Dao`.

Comment: Besides import statements, you shouldn't have the word `Map` in your code _anywhere_ without a `<` after it, and the same with `List`.